# How to add an image after specific frames in ffmpeg

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg.exe in C#. I want to add a frame or an image after a specific number of frames in a video. Like, I want to add an image after every 100 frames without losing audio of that video. Kindly tell me the command to do this.
Thank You.

Comment: "Without losing audio" You are adding an additional frame once every 100 frames. In a typical 29.97 FPS video, that amounts to a new frame every few seconds. This _will_ screw with the audio synchronization.

Comment: Is there any method to add an image after some frames and audio will be synchronized as well?

Comment: The audio is synchronized _to the frames_. If you add new frames, you need to resync the audio as well.